Linux でファンの状態を確認するには？
Linuxにおいて、ファンを認識するには、どのようなコマンドまたは確認をすればよいですか？
ちなみに、lm-sensorsなどを使用しても、以下の通りファンは表示されません。どのようにすればよいでしょうか？
acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +26.8°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:        +26.8°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +47.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

CMB1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          16.67 V
curr1:         0.00 A

環境:
# $uname -a

Linux Debian 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# #dmidecode -t baseboard

#dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 10 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: FUJITSU
        Product Name: FJNB1E8
        Version:
        Serial Number:
        Asset Tag:
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board

その他
PC:FMV-E8280
CPU:intel Core 2 Duo
OS:Debian

debianでは無いですが、こちらの記事でlm-sensorsに設定ファイルを作って値を調整する仕組みが解説されています。ファンスピード制御 何か参考になるかも。

該当機種の マニュアル を見る限り、BIOS 画面でもファンの情報は表示されないようなので、そもそもハード的に情報が取得できていないのではないでしょうか？

ええ、そうです。BIOSには、何もありません。ノートPCを開けてみたら何かわかるでしょうか？
